# div toggle script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry, I didnt explain this very well, I've set up what I have in jsfiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/greggb/Ya2wX/

basically what I'm trying to do is make it so after the first div has been opened, the second tab anchor (two) will close the first div before opening the next div?

Thanks, Gregg.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.example2').hide().before('');
      $('a#toggle-example2').click(function() {
           $('.example2').slideToggle(500);
           return false;
      });
 });

 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.item1').hide().before('');
      $('a#toggle-item1').click(function() {
           $('.item1').slideToggle(500);
           return false;
      });
 });
```

Comment: What does the `before('')` do ???

Comment: Show us html or put it on jsfiddle.com

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a#toggle-item1').click(function() {
```

An id should uniquely identify one element in a page . . . .if you are using ID 'toggle item 1' for other divs this won't work . . . .try using unique ids or a class

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $('.item1').hide();
      $('.item1').click(function() {
           $('.item1').not(this).hide();
           $(this).slideToggle(500);
           return false;
      });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a `toggle_item` class on the `<a>` elements, and do:

```
<a href="#" class="toggle-item">link 1</a>
<div class="item">content 1</div>

<a href="#" class="toggle-item">link 2</a>
<div class="item">content 2</div>
```

js:

```
$(function() {
      $('.item').hide();
      $('a.toggle-item').click(function() {
           $(this).next('.item').slideToggle(500);
           return false;
      });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/awCmz/)

Answer (score 0):

There may be a shorter method but this should work (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/6N4kJ/13/):

```
// When item 1 is clicked           
$('#item1').click(function() {
    // if item 2 is visible
    if ($('.item2').is(':visible')) {
        // hide (toggle) item2, and when finished..
        $('.item2').slideToggle(500, function() {
            // toggle item1
            $('.item1').slideToggle(500);
        });
    // else, just hide item1
    } else {
        $('.item1').slideToggle(500);
    }
});
```